# encode csv lines in csv file to utf8

Tags: python, csv, utf-8

I'm looking for a way to encode URL saved in lines of my csv file to utf8 , but couldnt till now find the right library to do it ,
the idea will be a library that read from csv lines and then encode to utf8 to put it may be in an other file or new column ,

Any body have an idea ?

to add an example :

I have a file that contain one column which is details :

containing some text , that I need after to pass in a url but encoded in utf .

like one line is:

> Créez, testez et déployez des applications sur Oracle Cloud — gratuitement. Inscrivez-vous une fois et accédez à deux offres gratuites.

and the result expected is for this line is :

> Cr%C3%A9ez%2C%20testez%20et%20d%C3%A9ployez%20des%20applications%20sur%20Oracle%20Cloud%20%E2%80%94%20gratuitement.%20Inscrivez-vous%20une%20fois%20et%20acc%C3%A9dez%20%C3%A0%20deux%20offres%20gratuites.

this is just an example of one line in my csv file , I need to apply this for all the line ,

well I found a solution and its working but not that correct :

```
import pandas as pd
from urllib.parse import quote

data = pd.read_csv("file_decoded.csv",error_bad_lines=False)


def title_parse(details):
    details = quote(details)
    return details


data['details']= data.details.apply(title_parse)
data.to_csv('file_encoded.csv')
```

the issue with this function is the text is encoded but it does take it as ascci code base , I dont know how to explain it

Comment: Can you share an example of your csv data as it is, and how you want it to be?  It isn't very clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I just edit my question , you can find details in my first request

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("filename.csv")
data.to_csv("filename_new.csv", encoding="utf-8")
```

Comment: this one dosent give the url encoded to utf8 like this example :  urlencoded = Freddie%20tentent%20de%20l'aider%20%C3%A0%20le%20chercher.%20Spencer%20retrouve%20des%20tickets%20du%20Funk%20E%20Fester's%20et%20d%C3%A9cide%20de%20remporter%20le%20plus%20gros%20lot%2C%20Murray%2C%20le%20dauphin%20magique...